# How to select the second instance of strong tag by class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://check-for-flooding.service.gov.uk/station/8208"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
for each_div in soup.findAll('strong',{'class':'defra-flood-statistics__impact'}):
    print each_div
```

I've tried seemingly everything including all kinds of nth-of-type variations but I just keep getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`.

I'm interested in the river level which is currently about 1m but I can't select it on its own for some reason.

```html
...
<dd class="defra-flood-statistics__value">
   <strong class="defra-flood-statistics__impact defra-flood-statistics__impact--normal">
   Normal
   </strong>
   0.05m to 1.90m <span class="govuk-visually-hidden">level here</span>
</dd>
...
<dd class="defra-flood-statistics__value">
   <strong class="defra-flood-statistics__impact">
   1.00m
   </strong>
   at <time datetime="">2:30pm</time> today
</dd>
...
```

Comment: is there a reason you use "lxml" instead of "html.parser"?

Comment: no, no reason! Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *This do not cause the issue but use in newer code `find_all()` instead of the old syntax `findAll()`*

Script is still working and selecting your elements - Just pick the second element from your resultset:

```
soup.find_all('strong',{'class':'defra-flood-statistics__impact'})[1].get_text(strip=True)
```

Output in moment of request:

```
0.96m
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://check-for-flooding.service.gov.uk/station/8208"
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
print(soup.find_all('strong',{'class':'defra-flood-statistics__impact'})[1].get_text(strip=True))
```